# How to check if an APK/AAB binary was signed in debug mode?

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

Let's say I am responsible of a tool to publish APK/AAB to play store and I need to do some pre-checks before doing so.

How can my tool check if an APK/AAB binary has been signed in "debug mode" ?

Note : to be clear, I don't need a process to sign it in "release mode" like in all other answers, I need the full check procedure to know if the APK/AAB will be refused by play store, so I can refuse it.

Comment: Checking the `AndroidManifest.xml` binary? But you'll a custom reader for that I think.

Comment: Yeah I've unzipped an APK and this file is no more readable. Anyway, I would need to know what to read in it exactly.

Comment: Ah.. My memory is a bit fuzzy about it. Maybe `Cert Issuer:`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first answer, waiting for better :

```
jarsigner -verify -certs -verbose my.aab > presign.txt
```

Now my.aab is in debug mode if and only if "presign.txt" contains "**CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US**".

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisite is bundletool, you can run  **brew install bundletool** to install it
After that run the following command in terminal, the result ist
0 if your .aab file is release otherwise 1:

`bundletool dump manifest --bundle= yugPathToYourAABFile | grep -c android:debuggable="true"`

if output is 0, bundle tool didnt find the android:debuggable="true" tag
1 means tag is found
You can also take ref from the following android doc:

````
Whether or not the application can be debugged, even when running on a device in user mode — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". ```
````

Comment: Hey! It would be a lot more helpful for people if you provide more context on what this command does? how to use it? what do the flags mean? Thanks!

Comment: Basically, this command checks whether a debug flag is present in your aab/apk